# Why is the version of transmission not the most recent?

Tags: 11.04, bittorrent, transmission

Why is in Natty old version of Transmission 2.13?

Current version in 2.22 released on March 4th.

Answer (score 4):

It hasn't made it's way into the Official Natty repos yet, because for the release, they need to have things stable.  I believe that Transmission was part of the [Debian Import Freeze](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebianImportFreeze), however I'm not 100% sure on that. It could have been part of the [Feature Freeze](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FeatureFreeze) back in February, but again, I'm not sure.

*Above info is found in the [Natty Release Schedule Wiki Page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyReleaseSchedule)*
However, if you're feeling adventurous, you can take a look at this question:

[What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/)

The PPA you want to add is this:
`ppa:transmissionbt/ppa`

*from the [Transmission site](http://www.transmissionbt.com/download/)*

Comment: @Alaukik Why did you completely remove the terminal instructions? Did you not ask [this question](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1122/isnt-ask-ubuntu-targeted-towards-end-users-gui-rather-than-advanced-command/1124#1124) on meta and accepted the answer that says "add GUI, but leave other"?